# Exception java.lang.NullPointerException when try to run MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap

Tags: android, kotlin

So this problem has make me scratching my head for sometimes now

I have a kotlin program that taking picture and adding watermark.
for most phone it's doing fine without error..

but with one phone it's always catch exception java.lang.NullPointerException

> the phone is Xiaomi Redmi Note 7

```
fun takePicture(){
 val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

        val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            "com.example.poneksimsfa.fileprovider",
            createImageFile()
        )
            uripic = photoURI
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)

            try {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
}
```

The createImageFile function is below

```
private fun createImageFile(): File {

        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val filename = "${timeStamp}_"
        val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            filename,
            ".jpg",
            storageDir
        ).apply {
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }

    }
```

and for OnActivityResult :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 2) {
            try
            {
                var pic : Bitmap? = null
                pic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver,uripic)
            }
            catch (E:Exception){
                val name = object{}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name
                errorlog(this,E, name, localClassName)
            }
        }
    }
```

The Exception that i got is : 21/7/2023 10:44:11 ; customer.CustomerDetailActivity ; onActivityResult => java.lang.NullPointerException: uri

I want to solve the error that occured on only one phone

Comment: I don't see any variable named `uri` in your code. Make sure you are posting the correct error message and relevant code correctly. The error message should have pointed you to the exact line which caused the error.

Comment: i think the error come from this line: 
pic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver,uripic)

because the exception catch from onactivityresult

Comment: I assume you didn't copy the error message completely and the variable causing NullPointerException is actually `uripic` instead of `uri`?

Comment: hello Ricky, below me is full exception that got caught.. it's uri.. 

21/7/2023 10:26:21 ; customer.CustomerDetailActivity ; onActivityResult => java.lang.NullPointerException: uri 
21/7/2023 10:26:50 ; customer.CustomerDetailActivity ; onActivityResult => java.lang.NullPointerException: uri 
21/7/2023 10:27:24 ; customer.CustomerDetailActivity ; onActivityResult => java.lang.NullPointerException: uri 
21/7/2023 10:44:11 ; customer.CustomerDetailActivity ; onActivityResult => java.lang.NullPointerException: uri

Comment: I try on the working phone, and try **nulling uripic** before **getBitmap**.. it gave me exactly same error

Comment: Please dont post logcat lines as comment. Put them in a code block in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned a value to variable uripic indeed. But if you start the Camera app your activity is not the top one anymore.

If an activity is not the top one it can be killed at any moment by Android OS.

If the Camera app closes your activity will be recreated if it was killed.

In a recreated activity your variable will be null.

Comment: Hey i also think that would be the problem, but even i try to assign the variable to shared preferences.. it would null when i try to take photo..

Comment: Of course not. And you should not use shared preferences for this but overwrite onSaveInstanceState() (or something like that) as it is especially there for your use case.

Comment: hey blackapps, i have try to save the uripic inside onSaveInstanceState() before shared preferences with no avail

Comment: Then you did something wrong. And we know not what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i solved the problem by going with 3rd party camera apps (fotoApparat) and replacing getBitmap function with the Glide library.. i don't know which one cause the problem (either Android OS or Built in camera) and i didn't care to find out.

for any one that want to try my solution.

here is my new onActivityResult() using Glide to process bitmap

```
if (requestCode == 2 ) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            try
            {
                var stringtofile = data!!.getStringExtra("uristring")
                val dialog = Dialog(this)
                val tv = dialogBuilder("Tunggu proses foto!",dialog,R.layout.custom_wait, false)

                Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(File(stringtofile))
                    .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                            dialog.dismiss()
                            currentPhotoPath = File(stringtofile).absolutePath
                            getCurrentLocation(resource)
                        }
                        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

                        }
                    })
            }
            catch (E:Exception){
                val name = object{}.javaClass.enclosingMethod.name
                errorlog(this,E, name, localClassName)
            }
        } 
    }
```

And here is my new class for calling fotoApparat

```
class ApparatCameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var binding: ActivityApparatCameraBinding
var photoResult:PhotoResult? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityApparatCameraBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    var fotoapparat = Fotoapparat(this,camera_view)
    fotoapparat.start()
    binding.run {

        btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener {
            photoResult = fotoapparat.takePicture()
            val photoResultx = photoResult
            thread {
                photoResultx!!.toBitmap().await()
                fotoapparat.stop()
                runOnUiThread{
                    btnTakeRetakeOkaySwitch(true)
                }
            }

        }

        btnRetake.setOnClickListener {
            btnTakeRetakeOkaySwitch(false)
            fotoapparat.start()
        }

        btnOkay.setOnClickListener {
            createImageFile(object : OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onImageSaved(file: File) {
                    fotoapparat.start()
                    photoResult!!.saveToFile(file)
                        .whenAvailable { bitmapPhoto ->
                            intent.putExtra("uristring", file.toString())
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)
                            finish()
                        }
                }
            })

        }
    }
}

interface OnImageSavedCallback {
    fun onImageSaved(file: File)
}

fun btnTakeRetakeOkaySwitch(boolean: Boolean){
    if (boolean == true)
    {
        btnTakePicture.visibility = View.GONE
        btnRetake.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        btnOkay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    else
    {
        btnTakePicture.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        btnRetake.visibility = View.GONE
        btnOkay.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun createImageFile(callback: OnImageSavedCallback) {
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val filename = "${timeStamp}_"
    val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val file = File.createTempFile(filename, ".jpg", storageDir)
    callback.onImageSaved(file)
}
```

}

Also dont forget to change your startActivityResult to new Activity.

Thanks for all the peoples that help answering.